# I wanted to know how the following patterns works

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, delimiter

**I am using the following pattern below to split the string 
and based on the pattern save token  to an array**

```
String[] s1=s.trim().split("[ !,?._'@]+");
```

Comment: You can take a look here [Regular Expression Java](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) You will find your answer here.

Comment: Do you know about this Web site: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

**Regex Explaination:**

`[]` Match any character in the set inside this.

Match a `SPACE` or `!` or `,` or `?` or `.` or `_` or `'` or `@` character.

`+` Match 1 or more (as many times as they appear) of the preceding token.

---

So, your code will divide the string s from at every occurance of these characters " !,?._'@" and put it into string array s1.